# AngularJS after run module action

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module

Is there a possibility of launching AngularJS function after the application?

Something like function `afterRun()` ?

This is to ensure that when the application starts to perform some jquery-scripts.

Comment: Wouldn't these jQuery-scripts normally be something you put in directives?

Comment: @Alxandr, now i do so. But i often faced with the task of running scripts after the application is launched. Maybe there is a more beautiful way to solve the problem than to write a directive that will work after the application ..